# How to execute selenium-webdriver commands in selenium-ide execute script command?

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, ionic-framework, selenium-ide, ionic-react

I'm testing my react ionic project using selenium-ide, there is no available commands in selenium-ide that focus on an input or a popup (Modal).
I guess that we have more options to execute using selenium-webdriver that allow us to have more control on our commands.

So my question for you is how to execute selenium-webdriver commands in selenium-ide?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own commands for the IDE.

https://selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/plugins/adding-commands

It is necessary that in the manifest you indicate as dependency "selenium-webdriver".

This is an example: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/tree/trunk/packages/side-plugin-example/src